# How to add Manufacturer filter in the left bar

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I am learning magento 1.9.

I need to add Manufacturer filter in the left bar along with Category and Filter. I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912344/how-to-add-manufacturer-attribute-to-filter-results-in-magento-layered-navigatio) link and tried same thing but it didn't work.

Even in that post, that solution is not marked as the correct one. Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Comment: RAJA,Can you please tell is manufuture is dropdown or multi select attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Manufacturer is dropdown and multi select attribute` then if `will automatically call of left filter.`

For this,you need check this attribute  setting

`Use In Layered Navigation` should be `Yes`.

**Also,**

`Use In Search Results Layered Navigation` make it `Yes`.

Please check at `admin>Catalog>Attribute>Manage Attribute> Select Your attribute Manufacturer` and check this above seeting.

Also, You need to `assign this attribute` to  `each attibute sets`  . Check this at  `admin>Catalog>Attribute>Manage Attribute set` .

Comment: You are great Amit. Thank you. I spent lots of time for this but this was just 5 min job. thank you again.

Comment: Every time I do any change, I need to rebuild indexes and/or clear cache. Is there any setting which makes sure that this thing happen automatically? Is there any issue if we make this to happen automatic?

Comment: Amit, the manufacturer filter is not coming as multi-select. Once I click any of the value in the manufacturer box, that manufacturer filter gets added on top of the filter list and the filter box of manufacturer disappears.

Comment: Amit, can you please help me in making the manufacturer filter as multi select?

Comment: yes sure.. i will help you